# How to remove blank lines before doctype in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Hi all i am the next issue

this is my source code of my index i am using wordpress 3

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

the problem is it have 5 blank lines before the doctype i revised the functions php in my template and nothing, i am try removin blank lines in the index and header file.
Have a possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there any blank lines at the start of `header.php` or `index.php` in your theme that are **not** wrapped in `<?php ?>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a WP plugin, such as a code minifier (WP minify, etc.). It will compress your pages removing the useless characters (blank lines, tabulations, etc.).